# Groovy code editor suggestions

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I'm trying to learn Grails.
I'm using SpringSource toole suite.
I expected to find code-completion, syntax highlighting and more things like that in the IDE.
Nothing like that! 
Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you enable the Groovy and Grails support? It's not there by default but it's trivial to configure. See http://grails.org/STS+Integration/

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ from JetBrains has all [that and more](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html).  It's not free, but the price is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Mac, you can use TextMate and install [Groovy/Grails](https://github.com/textmate/groovy-grails.tmbundle) bundle. You will have code snippets, that is some kind of completion.

If you're on Windows/Linux/Mac you can use [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/), that was made for(and in) Ruby but has Groovy/Grails support. It also have code snippets.

I strongly recommend for learning that you don't use object inspection and dynamical code completion in a dynamic language in order to avoid IDE addiction and dependency.

I personally prefer unobtrusive code editor, that let we deal with textcode directly without clutter, allowing us to make mistakes early and understand better the language (and the framework). I use it even in production work.

Answer (score 1):

I second [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html), but [the free edition could suffice, it has groovy support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), though Grails support is in the paid version only.

Comment: It is possible to use Community Edition for Grails projects, but you'll miss out on a lot of great features. You'll get Groovy code completion though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) Community Edition. As I see, the difference between free editors is not much. In face, I use IntelliJ Community just because of its simple interface. It also supports  syntax highlight/code completion for groovy/java, & somehandy functions like search/go to...

In short, if you want full support, the IntelliJ Premium is great, but you must pay for it. For the free rest, you can even choose any editors you want.

Answer (score 0):

i use IntelliJ Ultimate and it's the best way to go but if you want a free solution then Netbean 6.5 an up supports groovy/grails code highlight / Code completion natively and is free.